# How in Flutter do I pinpoint a potential memory issue when it crashes and DevTools disappears?

Tags: ios, flutter, memory

I have an app that loads videos from urls and the assets folder.

A single screen may have seven videos in memory all at once.

I'm using the Video Player library (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

When I exit the screen I override dispose and dispose of every video controller.

When I navigation between screens with videos the app eventually crashes. It simply says `Lost Connection to Device`.

I ran the app through Xcode because Xcode can tell me something useful to go on. As I was expecting, the app is crashing from memory pressure.

Unfortunately, due to how Flutter is built I can't run the app through Instruments and I have to rely on DevTools. DevTools doesn't stay around when an app crashes, so it's impossible to see any memory issues it might be trying to tell me.

How can I debug memory pressure in Flutter if there's no profiling tools that can help?

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest that you do is to run your app in Xcode and then open Instruments separately and attach it to your application process. That way you should be able to see what is causing the memory hog.

Comment: I have tried this, but if you're on iOS 14+ then it's impossible to run Instruments with a flutter app on a phone. Flutter apps can only be run if you use AS, VS, or Xcode, and if you try to run Instruments then it shuts the app off making the only way to run the app through Instruments is by hitting the Record button. But the Record button tries to run the app rather than compile the app through one of the IDEs, making it impossible to run Instruments with a Flutter app on a phone.